# Is there such thing as a RootController

Tags: angularjs

I have a navbar in my application that controls the routes for the entire application.  As such the navbar is in the index.html file.

Problem is that the navbar NavController is loaded when the page is loaded.  In that NavController I get the login information for the user.  The user information is used to determine which nav controls are shown, hence showHomeNav, showAdminNav.  The problem is the user is usually not logged in when the NavController is run hence nothing gets shown (which is correct). But when the user logs in I need to have the Navbar html recognize that and show the correct tabs.

As it stands I am not sure how to set the 'show' variables.  What I need to happen is to change the state of those variables in the LoginController as that is the controller that handles the login route and after login you will see the tabs you should see based on user access.

I think I could just check a $rootScope variable ($rootScope.user) in the NavBar HTML, and set $rootScope.user in the LoginController.  But I am not sure this is the right way to do it.

Here is a plunker of an example of how it stands.  Notice that after I login (simulate) the home and admin tabs do not show up.

http://plnkr.co/edit/zkqeAW?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts:

First, you *can* create your own "Root" controller.  You just need to add a controller somewhere above (hierarchically) the Login controller.  It might even make sense to add it to the `<html>` tag, or whichever tag `ng-app` is on.  There's nothing wrong with nested controllers.

However, I think the **right answer** in your case is to use a service to manage the login information.  This allows you to cleanly share the information across controllers, with hacking around.

A rough example:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory("LoginService", ["$location", "$timeout", function($location, $timeout) {
    var user = {};
    return {
        getUser: function() { return user; },
        login: function(userName, password) {
            $timeout(function() {
                user.role = 'ADMIN';
                $location.path("/about");
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller("SigninCtrl", ["$scope", "LoginService", function($scope, LoginService) {
  $scope.signin = function() {
      LoginService.login("foo", "abc123");
  }
}]);

app.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'LoginService', function ($scope, $location, LoginService) {
  $scope.user = LoginService.getUser();
  ...
}]);
```

[I've updated your Plunker code sample here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zr9u9L?p=preview).  I also had to modify `showHomeNav` and `showAdminNav` on the Nav controller to be functions, so they would dynamically change based on whether the user is logged in or not.

You'll probably want to tweak this a little, but you get the idea for how the `user` object lives within the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$rootScope.$broadcast` method that can relay events across the controller. It keeps the controller decoupled too.

[Here](http://www.plnkr.co/edit/PtMlQ8?p=preview) is the updated plunkr for that.